# after ffting in matlab should I switch left side of array and right side of aray?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to play a little with fft of song . I see the song as 2 dim [which I guess this is for stereo ] so I splitied it to 2 arrays and then I make it from only 1 columnn array to only 1 row array .
then I  wanted to see the fft of one of the array so I did what I thought I rememberd from class I took on matlab

```
    plot(abs(fft(song1dtag)));
```

from looking at the figure I got I see [image: figure1]

which in my opinion is wrong . this looks like an fft very good sin wave but the song I picked (girl you'll be a woman soon ....just saw pulp fiction few days back) has a very strong single man voice which might be true for the left part of the picture but I am having hard time seeing how the song has another very dominating part at 8.5 Khz[aprrox].

From the class I took I remember something which I dont know if it's true but what I remember is that the fft actually doing some problems because it cannot show from -pi to+pi so its taking the part of -pi to 0 and puts it in pi to 2pi .
1)Am I right about this ?
2)If I do then how do I overome it?
3)Also if we are on this topic the 0 to 10^6 x axis is the equivalentto 0 to 2pi?

edit1:
as @seuever suggested I used fftshift and now it looks more like what I expected :[image: after fftshift]

4) as I said in the song there is a one man singing . can I assume the middle frequency is the man's pitch? [I want to make 2 sound files . one with only voices and one with instruments]

Comment: You need to use `fftshift` to shift the center frequency to the middle

Comment: @Suever worked . thanks for the fast replay

Comment: Yes the frequency range is going to be `[-pi pi]`. The exact center is the overall power of the signal. You likely want to specify a certain frequency (not at the center) for the man singing. Using the `[-pi, pi]` range and # of samples you can convert to Hz and select an appropriate frequency for a male voice.

Comment: Maor or @Suever, please post an answer, so op can accepted it and close this question !

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to shift the center frequency to the middle of the spectrum.

```
plot(abs(fftshift(fft(song1dtag))));
```

If you want to convert the x-axis to frequency, you can use the number of samples combined with the knowledge that the spectrum spans `[-pi, pi]`. There is more information about this conversion [in the examples in the documentation for `fft`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#examples).